# How to Resolve Conflicting Lifecycle Mapping in Eclipse for Tycho and PDE

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, m2eclipse

I'm working on an Eclipse RCP project managed with Maven and Tycho. I've encountered a conflicting lifecycle mapping metadata error in Eclipse. The error message states:

Conflicting lifecycle mapping metadata (project packaging type="eclipse-plugin"): Mapping defined in 'org.eclipse.m2e.pde.connector_2.1.600.20240202-2240 [693]' and 'org.sonatype.tycho.m2e_0.10.0.20220926-1324 [701]'. To enable full functionality, remove the conflicting mapping and run Maven->Update Project Configuration.    pom.xml /ecu-configurator-core  line 13 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

I understand this conflict is between the m2e connector for PDE and Tycho. How can I resolve this conflict, and how can I locate the `org.eclipse.m2e.pde.connector` plugin to consider its removal? Which plugin should be removed to fix this, and what are the implications of removing each?

Additionally, what are the specific features provided by the Eclipse PDE (Plugin Development Environment) that I might lose if I remove the m2e PDE connector? I couldn't find `org.eclipse.m2e.pde.connector` in the Eclipse marketplace or installed plugins list.

Any guidance or resources for resolving these lifecycle mapping conflicts would be greatly appreciated.Or how can I build a multi Eclipse plugin project.

Comment: When or for what do you get the error (how can your issue be reproduced)? Have you imported the Eclipse plugin projects as Maven projects (which you shouldn't)? To build multiple Eclipse plugin projects, run the parent POM (with POM-less there might be only one `pom.xml` file). For editing and debugging you need Eclipse with PDE and the correct target platform to be set. Lifecycle mapping issues are related to Maven plugins and how to handle them in incremental project build. [You should not need any special connector for using Tycho](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/discussions/1290).